# Attempting solve rotation

Tags: math, rotation

Im working now with some mod for the game, exactly i need rotate my player to any object.
I have two vector3, its my pos and object pos.
As usually we can
Vector3 Dir = object - mypos to get direction and calculate yaw and pitch using atan2 function, write it to our player angle and we will done rotation.
Problem. I first time see pitch value between 180 (mouse up) and 360 (mouse down), yaw 0 - 360, roll 0 (doesn’t matter now). Its represents as Vector3 euler. Of course if im using atan2 way i getting incorrect values for this eluer vector cause i getting less small (Lower than 180) or negative values for pitch, yaw seems in range. How to calculate correct?

My calcs:

```
    Vector3 DoorDir = DoorOrigin - PlayerOrigin;
    DoorDir = NormalizeVec(DoorDir);

    float yaw = Rad2Deg(atan2(DoorDir.x, DoorDir.z));//Game has XZY coords.
    float pitch = Rad2Deg(-1.f * atan2(DoorDir.y, sqrtf(DoorDir.x * DoorDir.x + DoorDir.z * DoorDir.z)));   
    SetAngles(Vector2(yaw,pitch)//Sets angles (converted yaw and pitch back to DEG)
```

Comment: Please show your calculations. I can't really follow your problem description. Especially the part *"if I'm using atan2 way, I get incorrect values"*. Then it's either the wrong way or you use it wrong. For both cases, we would need to see what you tried.

Comment: Edited my original post

Comment: Looks good to me. Why do you think that negative pitch angles are wrong? They really should be between -90° and +90°.

Comment: Because this game angles haven't negative pitch values, it works from 180-360, if i set negative value or less 180 game just sets 180, if i set 179 game anyways set 180, if i set 181 game take 181.

Comment: Then we need to know what angle this is. It definitely is not a pitch angle in the usual sense.

Comment: Referenced as Vector3 euler

Comment: There are [12 different kinds of Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Chained_rotations_equivalence). We need to know which one.

Comment: If i understood correct, Tait–Bryan angles XZY accordings with game coordinate system, if i was wrong here, nvm. I will try hard solve my calcs.